# Red values after wheel alignment

Tags: honda, alignment, crv

I have a Honda CR-V 2009, and all 4 wheels went under a wheel alignment today. However toe value remained red at left rear, also total toe is out of specification. Rear strut assemblies were recently replaced. Do I have to worry about it?
Thanks,
Bence
[image: wheel alignment hondacrv]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL DR:** Probably very little to worry about.

On most vehicles, there is no way to adjust the alignment in the rear. Only the front has adjustment, and again for that, it is mainly the toe which can be affected. While toe has the greatest affect on tire wear, this usually isn't a problem, because on front wheel drive vehicles the rear tires are being pulled and not driven. While your CR-V may have four wheel drive, it is a front wheel drive vehicle when the 2WD mode is engaged.

The usual way the rear end can come out of alignment is through wear of suspension parts or due to some kind of damage. Conversely, the only way to make the adjustments if either of these things are true is to fix the offending parts. You can check for wear on any of these parts yourself, though most shops who do alignments check these parts during the alignment and will tell you if there's an issue (usually). Why would they do that? For two reasons. First, it's a waste of your time/money to do an alignment if your vehicle has worn or damaged parts. Second, there's a chance you'll have them do the work to fix any of these parts if they bring the issue up to you, which means they'll make more money from you.

There may be aftermarket parts which can be placed which can affect the rear-end alignment to get it into spec, but these types of parts are only used on performance vehicles for track type purposes. I'm doubting your CR-V would be a candidate for parts like this, but they may be available if you do a search for them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply!